# MySQLdb and _mysql version mismatch

Tags: python, sql, ubuntu

I am currently getting the following mismatch error when running some code on Spyder in Ubuntu:

```
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0)
```

Naturally, I have tried to match the version by using:

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
pip install mysql-python==version.x.y.z
```

and

```
pip uninstall mysqlclient
pip install mysqlclient==version.x.y.z
```

However, I am getting errors because there is no version 1.2.5 for "_mysql" and no version 1.4.6 for "MySQLdb" and therefore cannot match them. The ubuntu terminal displays all the available versions for each item and there is not a version that is present on both an therefore I cannot match.

If somebody could assist me with solving this issue I would be hugely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

What are you seeing when you display the available versions for each package? It could be a conflicting install between pip and apt as suggested here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/372580/issue-getting-mysql-to-work-correctly